# Tap gesture dont work on UIImageview when animation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, imageview, tap

I made an animation and my imageviews slide right to left edge with UIView.animate. I want to tap the image views during animation but I can't.

By the way, `cloud` is a container view with the imageviews. I will give  animation to container view.

```
tapImage = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(goToDetail))
self.imgView1.addGestureRecognizer(tapImage!)

func animateTheClouds(cloud : UIView) {
    let cloudMovingSpeed = 3.0/view.frame.size.width
    let duration = (cloud.frame.origin.x + cloud.frame.size.width) * cloudMovingSpeed
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear,.allowUserInteraction,.allowAnimatedContent], animations: {
        cloud.frame.origin.x = -cloud.frame.size.width
    }, completion: {_ in
        // Reset back to the right edge of the screen
        if cloud.frame.origin.x <= 0{
            self.createGroupKanjiList()
            self.setImages()
            cloud.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
        }
        self.animateTheClouds(cloud: cloud)
    })
}
```

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227283/7734643

Comment: I m sad, even I made enabled All views and imageviews in my device but doesn't work :(

Comment: Try it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29727841/5233180

Comment: How did you check if the touch doesn't work?

Comment: İ give an finction with selector and doesnt call the function , normally i can tap imageview but when i give an animation i cant tap imageview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tap Gesture on animating UIView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998808/tap-gesture-on-animating-uiview-not-working)

Comment: ^its a duplicate. The only diff is your touches began logic needs to be on the container view holding the clouds but you will need to test the presentation layer of the cloud/image view.